# UISearchController not displaying results for 3 characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uisearchcontroller

I have it so when users type into a UISearchBar it filters the results like so:

```
#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating

-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *searchString = [self.searchController.searchBar text];
    [self updateFilteredContentForSaleName:searchString];
    [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Content Filtering
- (void)updateFilteredContentForSaleName:(NSString *)wordName {
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    for (PFObject *word in parseWords)
    {
        NSString *aWord = [word objectForKey:@"word"];
        if ([[aWord lowercaseString] containsString:[wordName lowercaseString]])
        {
            [self.searchResults addObject:word];
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is when words like 'lie' or anything with 3 characters (or less) are typed in, no results are displayed that are 3 character or less words.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is your code working for words of 4 characters or more?

Comment: It may be Parse.  When I build similar functionality, I don't return results for less than 3 characters (because there would be too many results and it would not be as useful).  Parse may be doing this to reduce the number of requests.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I'll email Parse and see what they have to say!